# Angular2 Heros Tutorial - How does child component get Service/Provider?

Tags: angular

I am going through the Angular2 Heros tutorial right now.

I am specifically [at this step](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html):

> Go back to the HeroesComponent and remove the HeroService from its providers array. We are promoting this service from the HeroesComponent to the AppComponent. We do not want two copies of this service at two different levels of our app.

app.comonent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <my-heroes></my-heroes>
    `,
    directives: [HeroesComponent],
    providers: [
        HeroService
    ]

})
export class AppComponent { 
    title = 'Main App';
}
```

heros.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  template: `
        ... bla bla bla ...
    `,

    styles:[`
          ... bla bla bla ...
    `],
    directives: [HeroDetailComponent],
    providers: [
        HeroService
    ]


})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit { 

    public heroes: Hero[];
    selectedHero: Hero;

    constructor(
        private heroService: HeroService
    ){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then( heroes => this.heroes = heroes );
    }

    onSelect = function (hero: Hero){
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }
}
```

**My question is**, when I remove the HeroService from the list of Providers in heros.components, why does this still work?

My assumption is that *since we have specified in the constructor* that we require a HeroService, one will be provided by the parent component (in this case app.component).  Is this accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the tutorial:](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

> The providers array tells Angular to create a fresh instance of the HeroService when it creates a new AppComponent. The AppComponent can use that service to get heroes **and so can every child component of its component tree.**

So your assumption is partly correct.
Actually your `app.component` creates **one** instance of your service, as soon as it gets injected by a child component. Since your `hero.component` is a child of `app.component` it will use the same instance. So not *just one*, it's *the one*.

Actually important to know that behaviour to avoid errors if your instancing a service multiple times, which is probably not what you want most of the time.

---

### Updated for additional info:

As Mark Rajcok pointed out correctly in his comment, the service is created as soon as one of the child components of `app.component` injects it. If no child component injects the service, there will no instance be created of that service.

And as Ed Morales added, there's another possibility to provide a service by using `viewProviders` instead of `providers` which will make the created instance only accessible by the providing component, instead for all of its childs.

Comment: Yes, adding to this anwser: `providers` array share the instance with the children components, while `viewProviders` array only create it for that component and its template.

Comment: I don't think the docs have that quite right.  The `providers` array registers a provider with the component's injector.  The HeroService doesn't get created when the AppComponent is created.  It gets created when a child component injects it (in its constructor).  Remove `<child></child>` from [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/32LYHQmqK8jRZ4nsXOWI?p=preview) and you'll see that an instance of the service is not created, because no component injected it.

Answer (score 3):

The `providers` array registers a class (or a function, or a pre-defined object, or a string) with a component injector.  E.g.,

```
providers: [HeroService]
```

This is actually a short-hand expression for

```
providers: [new Provider(HeroService, {useClass: HeroService})]
```

Essentially we register a "recipe" with the injector – i.e., we tell the injector how to create a `HeroService` (i.e., a dependency) when this component or one of its descendants injects `HeroService`.

We inject dependencies using the constructor.  E.g.,

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService)
```

When `HeroesComponent` injects `HeroService`, Angular does the following:

- It first looks to see if the requesting component's injector (i.e., `HeroesComponent`'s injector) has a recipe for creating a `HeroService`.  It does not (it is not in its `providers` array), so it goes up the component tree to its parent.
- It then checks to see if the parent component's injector (i.e., `AppComponent`'s injector) has a recipe for creating a `HeroService`.  It does.  The `AppComponent` injector then does the following:

  - If it previously created an instance of `HeroService`, if returns a reference to it.
  - Otherwise (i.e., this is the first component that is injecting/requesting `HeroService`) it does the following:

    - It uses the recipe to create an instance of `HeroService`.
    - It stores a reference to it (for other, possible requests for this dependency).
    - It returns a reference to it to the `HeroesComponent` that asked for the dependency.

`AppComponent`'s injector will only ever create one instance of `HeroService`.  That (one) instance can be injected into `AppComponent` and/or any of its descendants.